# Observable<Class[]> vs Observable<Class>[]

Tags: angular, observable

I wrote some small apps which all retrieve data from a database and display it.
To get the data I wrote a `Service` which returned a `Observable<Class[]>`.

In the meantime I noticed, that I don't understand Observables as good as I thought I would. Now I am wondering if an observabe of a list (`Observabel<Class[]>`) is the right choice for me or if a list of Observables (`Observable<Class>[]`) would be better.

Can someone explain to me which way I should go and why? I am interessted in all other information regarding Observables too.

Comment: Hard to tell without any info what you try to accomplish. `Observabel<Class[]>` is supposed to emits an array that contain `Class` instances with each event. `Observable<Class>[]` is an array of observables which is something entirely different. I guess what you want is either the former or `Observable<Class>` which is supposed to emit a `Class` instance with each event.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get multiple data (instances of `Class`) from your database you need `Observable<Class[]>`. You want to "observe" an array of instances in your subscriber.